Can we perform some action on metadata changed?
Whenever the metadata is changed in salesforce can we write any trigger or flow to identify that the change happened in metadata then we can perform some action like sending an email from the apex or flow.
For example, when a new custom field is created, updated or deleted, or field is added to the page layout, or a list view is changed then perform some action.
Thanks

In a general sense, no. For custom metadata types (which do not support triggers, and there is no access to CreatedDate or LastModifiedDate for their records), the SystemModstamp value is accessible through SOQL. You could, therefore, define a scheduled job that runs repeatedly (e.g. once a minute) looking for records that were recently changed and then "react" to those changes.

There is an open Idea for this requirement and I have also confirmed with the salesforce support team.
Salesforce Support Reply:

Salesforce doesn’t provide a built-in feature to automatically track
changes in metadata. Instead, you need to manually query the complete
metadata or specify the metadata you want to monitor and set up email
notifications.
example for fields and objects
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
<types>
<members>*</members>
<name>CustomObject</name>
</types>
<types>
<members>*</members>
<name>CustomField</name>
</types>
<version>56.0</version>
</Package>

You need to set up a schedule to periodically retrieve metadata,
compare it with the previous version, and send an email with the
updates.

